# Link assets images to my Products values stored in DB

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

Hi lets say I have a fixed number of products ( 5 products for example ) . In my HTML form, if i would like to use a form to display all products so that user can click purchase and I can capture what are the clicked data that user clicked on, how can i do so ? I would like to show the product's images as well.

As of now, this it is hardcoded.

```
%h1 <u>Fruit Basket</u>

.row
  .col-xs-10.col-sm-6.col-md-6.col-lg-4
    .thumbnail
      %img{:src => "assets/Garden3.jpg", :class => "FeedbackRegion"}/
      .caption
        %h3.PriceTag RM 60
        %button.btn.btn-primary.PurchaseBtn Purchase
        %p <b><u>Fruits:</b></u>
        %p Apple, Orange, Banana
        %p <b><u>Flowers :</b></u>
        %p Zebra, Chrysanthemum, Fern leafs

  .col-xs-10.col-sm-6.col-md-6.col-lg-4
    .thumbnail
      %img{:src => "assets/Garden3.jpg", :class => "FeedbackRegion"}/
      .caption
        %h3.PriceTag RM 80
        %button.btn.btn-primary.PurchaseBtn Purchase
        %p <b><u>Fruits:</b></u>
        %p Apple, Orange, Banana
        %p <b><u>Flowers :</b></u>
        %p Zebra, Chrysanthemum, Fern leafs
```

How can I remove those hardcoded codes and make it dynamic as in if I add another new product, I can get its information and its' product **IMAGE**.  I thought about PAPERCLIP gem but doesn't seems to be what i need here ? Do correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Paperclip is exactly what you need, but you need to start by properly using templating first. I'm going to assume you didn't realize you needed to iterate over your Products, and if that's not true, skip to step 2.

1. As you noted, you hardcoded each product item, not just the image, but the whole purchase shebang. Don't do that. Do something in your controller like `@products = Product.all`, and then do something in your embedded ruby in the view like

`@products.each do |p|
      image_tag "hi", p.image
      button_tag "other stuff"
      # etc.`

If you're not familiar with how to use embedded ruby in your views to load resources from your controllers, obviously that's first; read the docs to learn how to do that on your own.

2. And now you're going to have to store the `p.image` as an `image` column in your products database. Paperclip will do that for you, and that way you can load the images directly from your own database per resource, so that the right image will be loaded each time.